# Why I can't import the image inside a component Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, path, vuex

None of the methods placing the image as a tag or a background image works. Even though the path is correct. Written with the official docs. I've also tried installing vue-loader and giving a img src path, but it did'n help either.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-fsg2l2?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHeader.vue,src%2Frouter%2Findex.js,src%2Fviews%2FHome.vue,src%2Fviews%2FShops.vue,src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue

```js
<template>
  <a href="#" class="header__top-item facebook" :style="image"> </a>
  <img alt="" src="../assets/icons/facebook-header.svg" />
  <img v-bind:src="require('../assets/icons/facebook-header.svg')" />
</template>

<script>
  data() {
    return {
      image: { backgroundImage: 'url(../assets/icons/facebook-header.svg)' },
    };
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vue.js, you can import and use images inside a component by using the require function or by importing the image directly.

Try this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="require('@/assets/icons/facebook-header.svg')" alt="Facebook Icon" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: :src="require('../assets/icons/facebook-header.svg')" didn't help. I've also read I there's no need for require if you use vue-loader

Comment: :src="require('@/assets/icons/facebook-header.svg')" asks me to install assets package ...